# how to prove that a function is infinitely differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm studying functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d = 1, 2 ,3 $ and I'm trying to give a function let be infinitely differentiable and has compact support. For $d=1$ I know

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
       \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2 - 1}\right) & if\quad |x|<1\\
       0                                   & if\quad |x|\geq 1  
      \end{array}\right.$$

and for $d=3$, someone suggests me consider this analog function

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
       \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{||x||^2 - 1}\right) & if\quad ||x||<1\\
       0                                   & if\quad ||x||\geq 1  
      \end{array}\right.$$

where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm.

Can someone explain how to I prove that this function is infinitely differentiable.

Thanks

Comment: If $f$ is infinitely differentiable then so is $f(\|x\|^{2})$ simply because $\|x\|^{2}$ is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @geetha290krm I had written same, but it is $f(\|x\|)$ so a little more finesse is needed.

Comment: Actually, you $f(x)=e^{-1/t}$ for $t >0$ and $f(0)=0$ also  defines an infinitely differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-{1 \over x}},& x>0 \\
0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Clearly $\phi$ is smooth for $x\neq 0$, so the only possible point of contention would be $x=0$.

I claim that for $x>0$ we have $\phi^{(k)}(x) = p_k({1 \over x}) e^{-{1 \over x}}$ for some polynomial $p_k$. This is clealy true for $k=0$, so suppose it is true for $k=0,...,n$.

Differentiating $\phi^{(n)}$ gives
$\phi^{(n+1)} = ({1 \over x^2} p_n(x) + p_n'(x) ) e^{-{1 \over x}}$, and since $x \mapsto {1 \over x^2} p_n(x) + p_n'(x)$ is a polynomial we see the result is true for all $n$.

To see differentiability at $x=0$, first note that
for $x>0$ and for any $n$, $e^{-{1 \over x}} = {1 \over e^{{1 \over x}}} \le {1 \over { 1 \over n! x^n}} = n! x^n$. In particular, for any polynomial $p$ we can find some $K$ such that for $0 < x \le 1$ we have $|p({1 \over x}) e^{-{1 \over x}}| \le K x^2$.

Note first that $|\phi(x)-\phi(0)| \le K_1 x^2$ for $|x| \le 1$ and so $\phi'(0) = 0$.

Now suppose $\phi^{(k)}$ is differentiable for $k=0,...,n$ and that $\phi^{(k)}(0) = 0$. From above we see that
$| \phi^{(n)}(x) -\phi^{(n)}(0)| \le K_n x^2$ and hence $\phi^{(n+1)}(0) = 0$.

In particular, $\phi$ is smooth everywhere.

Since $n(x)=\|x\|^2-1$ is smooth, we see that $f = \phi \circ n$ is smooth.